# Cannot get notifications when my Ionic 3 app is in foreground ( For iOS ), Android works fine

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, apple-push-notifications

The payload I am sending is fine, searched for this a lot, Android foreground notifications are working fine. And in iOS, when the app is in the background or app is closed, I receive notification correctly.

But when the app is in the foreground, I don't get the notification, neither the .on('notification', ()=>{}) is triggered. Any ideas would be helpful.

Already gone through a lot of stuff.

```
const options: PushOptions = {
   android: {},
   ios: {
     "sound": "true",
     "alert": "true",
     "badge": "true",
     "clearBadge": "true"
   },
   windows: {},
   browser: {
       pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
   }
};

const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

pushObject.on('notification')
.subscribe((notification: any) => {
  // {
  //   additionalData: {
  //     typeData: {}//Sent from server,
  //     coldstart: "false",
  //     foreground: "false"
  //   }
  // }

  let alertme = this.alert.create({
    title : "GOT NOTIFIED",
    subTitle : JSON.stringify( notification ),
    buttons : [{
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: () => {
      }
    }]
  });
  alertme.present();
});
```

Comment: When i click the notification in iOS, the .on('notification', ()=>{}) is triggered!

Comment: Sharing some code will also be helpful.

Comment: Added, please see now, This is the basic code. Everything is working fine on Android, but on iOS it's working when app is not active. But when app is active I don't get any notification, .on('notification') is not triggered!

Comment: When I click on the notificatoin in iOS, .on('notification') is triggered!!

Comment: Have you fixed this problem?

Comment: Yes, documentation and firebase certificates fixed it.